# How to update the result of an operation constantly based on input from the console in Python?

Tags: python, input, user-input

to evaluate the area of a region based on 2D coordinates (latitude and longitude), I ask the user to introduce the latitude and longitude (in that order, in two individual messages for each point).

When the user has just written one or two points, there is a message telling that area cannot be calculated yet. In order to make this program valuable, it should work with infinite points, and I have not figured out how to update for each point all the latitude and longitude coordinates introduced, without writing manually each one of them (I do not need to tell if the point introduced is the second of eighth):

```
geod = Geod(ellps='WGS84')



lat_1 = float(input("Input the latitute of the first coordinate:"))

lon_1 = float(input("Input the longitude of the first coordinate:"))

print("More information is needed to calculate the area")



lat_2 = float(input("Input the latitute of the second coordinate:"))

lon_2 = float(input("Input the longitude of the second coordinate:"))

print("Area cannot be calculated yet")



lat_3 = float(input("Input the latitute of the third coordinate:"))

lon_3 = float(input("Input the longitude of the third coordinate:"))

lats = [lat_1, lat_2, lat_3]

lons = [lon_1, lon_2, lon_3]

poly_area, poly_perimeter = geod.polygon_area_perimeter(lons, lats)

print("Area:", (abs(float(poly_area))) / (1000000), "km^2")

print("Perimeter:", (abs(float(poly_perimeter))) / (1000), "km")



lat_4 = float(input("Input the latitude of the fourth coordinate:"))

lon_4 = float(input("Input the longitude of the fourth coordinate:"))

lats = [lat_1, lat_2, lat_3, lat_4]

lons = [lon_1, lon_2, lon_3, lon_4]

poly_area, poly_perimeter = geod.polygon_area_perimeter(lons, lats)

print("Area:", (abs(float(poly_area))) / (1000000), "km^2")

print("Perimeter:", (abs(float(poly_perimeter))) / (1000), "km")
```

The first line (geod) and the poly_area are required to evaluate the area according to Earth surface.

I would like to know how to make a loop in which the lats and lons lines are updated.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This code will add coordinates as tuples to a lists until you enter a non-numeric value in one of the fields.

```
coordinates = []
while True:
    latitude = input("Enter your latitude: ")
    if not latitude.isnumeric():
        break
    longitude = input("Enter your longitude: ")
    if longitude.isnumeric():
        coordinate = (latitude, longitude)
        coordinates.append(coordinate)
        print(f"Added coordinates {coordinate}")
    else:
        break
print(coordinates)
```

It will look like this:

```
Enter your latitude: 15
Enter your longitude: 85
Added coordinates ('15', '85')
Enter your latitude: 34
Enter your longitude: 97
Added coordinates ('34', '97')
Enter your latitude: hello
[('15', '85'), ('34', '97')]
```

You can then iterate over the coordinates list using e.g. a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyproj import Geod

geod = Geod(ellps='WGS84')

lats = []
lons = []
count = 0
while True:
    count += 1
    lat = float(input(f"Input latitute #{count}: "))
    lon = float(input(f"Input longitude #{count}: "))
    lats.append(lat)
    lons.append(lon)

    if count < 3:
        print("More information is needed to calculate the area.")
        continue

    poly_area, poly_perimeter = geod.polygon_area_perimeter(lons, lats)
    print("Area:", (abs(float(poly_area))) / (1000000), "km^2")
    print("Perimeter:", (abs(float(poly_perimeter))) / (1000), "km")

    if input('Continue entering more coordinates?  ') in ['n', 'N', 'No']:
        break
```

Thank you to the person that helped.

coordinates[] did not work with the poly_area function because it required two inputs.